# Code not working. Notification that should go off once a day

Tags: java, android, xml

So I don't know why this code is not working. I wanted to make an "alarm" notification that would go off once a day. Just wanted to say im new to android. Thanks.

*Edit*: Changed up the code a bit. Alarm method executes and the notification does too, but I get this error message:

> -248/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.polakken.test/.lol (has extras) }: not found 06-13 00:00:00.825 231-267/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager 06-13 00:00:00.825 231-248/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager –

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int i = preferences.getInt("numberoflaunches", 1);

        if (i < 2) {
            alarmMethod();
            i++;
            editor.putInt("numberoflaunches", i);
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            splashMethod();

        }




    }

//...

private void alarmMethod() {
        Intent intentbro = new Intent(this, lol.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intentbro, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "start alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

//notification class

public class lol extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent1, 0);


        b.setContentText("lol");
        b.setContentTitle("Default notification");
        b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconography_small_size);
        b.setContentIntent(pIntent);







        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());




    }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your happening if anything?  Are you getting errors?  If so, post them.

Comment: @JNYRanger problem is there are no errors. application runs perfectly yet fails to display notifications on the time listed in the code

Comment: You should test with an upcoming calendar time, and set breakpoints in your code.  See if your breakpoints execute, and tell us which part of your code isn't working as expected.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky added logs. Everyting executes. 07-30 13:14:26.560    9649-9649/com.example.polakken.test I/tester﹕ Alarm on
07-30 13:14:26.560    9649-9649/com.example.polakken.test I/tester﹕ On create works

Comment: Did you put breakpoints in your alarmMethod()?  Do you even know if it executes?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky i changed the code up a bit. Alarm method executes while the notification does not. I took the notification into separate class. I get an arror -248/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.polakken.test/.lol (has extras) }: not found
06-13 00:00:00.825      231-267/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
06-13 00:00:00.825      231-248/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager

Comment: @DavidMinesote Are you trying to start an explicit Service or BroadcastReceiver?  If so, did you define it in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alarm with notification, notification wont pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685020/alarm-with-notification-notification-wont-pop-up)

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you, you should accept the one that was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra day to your alarm. It should look like this:

```
...
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
...
```

Comment: Well the code above is scheduling a notification for 1:00am. It wouldn't go off till 1am!

Comment: Also, I am assuming you have your BroadcastReciever set up correctly. Please see this tutorial, especially the BorodcastReceiver section. http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: i changed clock to 1 am and 12:59 still wont run

Comment: So then why are you using the `alarmManager.setRepeating()` function?

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't have your BreoadcastReciever set up to receive the alarm. Look at the tutorial above - it will give you an idea of how to set it up, whether it is recurring or not. You need a BroadcastReciever to actually receive the alarm, then build and display a notification at that time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intentbro, 0);`

However, you need to declare this Service in your AndroidManifest like this:

```
<service android:name=".Lol" />
```

Also, classes in Java should be capitalized, but your Intent calls a lower-case class:

```
Intent intentbro = new Intent(this, lol.class);
```

I suggest you run static analysis on your code to see how to improve it!